# convert and process a dictionary to matrix in python

Tags: python

I have a big `list` in `python` like the following small example:

small example:

```
['GAATTCCTTGAGGCCTAAATGCATCGGGGTGCTCTGGTTTTGTTGTTGTTATTTCTGAATGACATTTACTTTGGTGCTCTTTATTTTGCGTATTTAAAAC', 'TAAGTCCCTAAGCATATATATAATCATGAGTAGTTGTGGGGAAAATAACACCATTAAATGTACCAAAACAAAAGACCGATCACAAACACTGCCGATGTTTCTCTGGCTTAAATTAAATGTATATACAACTTATATGATAAAATACTGGGC']
```

I want to make a `new list` in which every `string` will be converted to a `new list` and every list has some `tuples`. in fact I want to divide the length of each `string` by 10. the `1st tuple` would be `(1, 10)` and the `2nd tuple` would be `(10, 20)` until the end , depending on the length of the `string`. at the end, every `string` will be a `list of`tuples and finally I would have a `list of lists`.
in the small example the `1st string` has `100 characters` and the `2nd string` has `150 characters`. 
for example the expected output for the small example would be:

```
new_list = [[(1, 10), (10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40), (40, 50), (50, 60), (60, 70), (70, 80), (80, 90), (90, 100)],  [(1, 10), (10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40), (40, 50), (50, 60), (60, 70), (70, 80), (80, 90), (90, 100), (100, 110), (110, 120), (120, 130), (130, 140), (140, 150)]]
```

to make such list I made the following code but it does not return what I expect. do you know how to fix it?

```
mylist = []
valTup = list()
for count, char in enumerate(mylist):
    if count % 10 == 0 and count > 0:
        valTup.append(count)
    else:
        new_list.append(tuple(valTup))
```

Comment: What it return?

Comment: That example isn't a dictionary, it's a list containing a single string. Why are you looping over an empty list? What is your expected output for that DNA string?

Comment: Oh i corrected the question.

Comment: Why is the first item in the first tuple `1` but not `0`? Wouldn't `[[(0, 10), (10, 20), ...]` make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the package [boltons](https://boltons.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

boltons.iterutils

**boltons.iterutils.chunked_iter(src, size)** returns pieces of
the source iterable in size -sized chunks (this example was copied
from the docs):

```
>>> list(chunked_iter(range(10), 3))
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9]]
```

**Example:**

from boltons.iterutils import chunked_iter

```
adn = [
    'GAATTCCTTGAGGCCTAAATGCATCGGGGTGCTCTGGTTTTGTTGTTGTTATTTCTGAATGACATTTACTTTGGTGCTCTTTATTTTGCGTATTTAAAAC', 
    'TAAGTCCCTAAGCATATATATAATCATGAGTAGTTGTGGGGAAAATAACACCATTAAATGTACCAAAACAAAAGACCGATCACAAACACTGCCGATGTTTCTCTGGCTTAAATTAAATGTATATACAACTTATATGATAAAATACTGGGC'
    ]

result = []

for s in adn:
    result.append(list(chunked_iter(list(s), 10)))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following solutions, the first one based on your code, the second one taking only one line, and finally the third one which is my preferred solution based on `range()`, `zip()` and slicing:

```
mylist = ['GAATTCCTTGAGGCCTAAATGCATCGGGGTGCTCTGGTTTTGTTGTTGTTATTTCTGAATGACATTTACTTTGGTGCTCTTTATTTTGCGTATTTAAAAC',
          'TAAGTCCCTAAGCATATATATAATCATGAGTAGTTGTGGGGAAAATAACACCATTAAATGTACCAAAACAAAAGACCGATCACAAACACTGCCGATGTTTCTCTGGCTTAAATTAAATGTATATACAACTTATATGATAAAATACTGGGC']


# Here is the solution based on your code
resultlist = []

for s in mylist:
    valTup = []
    for count, char in enumerate(s, 1):
        if count % 10 == 0:
            valTup.append((count-10, count))
    resultlist.append(valTup)

print(resultlist)

# Here is the one-line style solution
resultlist = [[(n-10, n) for n,char in enumerate(s, 1) if n % 10 == 0] for s in mylist]

print(resultlist)

# Here is my preferred solution
resultlist = []

for s in mylist:
    temp = range(1+len(s))[::10]
    resultlist.append(list(zip(temp[:-1], temp[1:])))

print(resultlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
mylist = ['GAATTCCTTGAGGCCTAAATGCATCGGGGTGCTCTGGTTTTGTTGTTGTTATTTCTGAATGACATTTACTTTGGTGCTCTTTATTTTGCGTATTTAAAAC', 'TAAGTCCCTAAGCATATATATAATCATGAGTAGTTGTGGGGAAAATAACACCATTAAATGTACCAAAACAAAAGACCGATCACAAACACTGCCGATGTTTCTCTGGCTTAAATTAAATGTATATACAACTTATATGATAAAATACTGGGC']
new_list1 = list()
new_list2 = list()


for i in range(len(mylist[0])/10):
    if(10+i*10 <= len(mylist[0])):
        new_list1.append(mylist[0][0+i*10:10+i*10])
    else:
        new_list1.append(mylist[0][0+i*10:])
for i in range(len(mylist[1])/10):
    if(10+i*10 <= len(mylist[1])):
        new_list2.append(mylist[1][0+i*10:10+i*10])
    else:
        new_list2.append(mylist[1][0+i*10:])

new_list = [new_list1,new_list2]
```

> [['GAATTCCTTG',   'AGGCCTAAAT',   'GCATCGGGGT',   'GCTCTGGTTT',
>   'TGTTGTTGTT',   'ATTTCTGAAT',   'GACATTTACT',   'TTGGTGCTCT',
>   'TTATTTTGCG',   'TATTTAAAAC'],  ['TAAGTCCCTA',   'AGCATATATA',
>   'TAATCATGAG',   'TAGTTGTGGG',   'GAAAATAACA',   'CCATTAAATG',
>   'TACCAAAACA',   'AAAGACCGAT',   'CACAAACACT',   'GCCGATGTTT',
>   'CTCTGGCTTA',   'AATTAAATGT',   'ATATACAACT',   'TATATGATAA',
>   'AATACTGGGC']]